# I Can't upload image in media library

Tags: wordpress, image, post, media

Hope you guys fine. I am facing the issue while uploading image in WordPress. Whenever i try to upload the image error comes(v5-section-bg-1.png
**The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels**). Anyone who can help kindly guide me.

Comment: You need to include more details such as the error you get from the [Developer Console](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002197259-How-to-open-the-developer-console) when you try to upload the file. In my case it was a 408 timeout error that was resolved by following [this](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500010094662-Why-do-I-receive-a-408-Request-Timeout-error-when-uploading-large-files-to-my-site-).

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue, hard refresh in WordPress media library using `Control + Shift + R` solved a problem. I have no idea why...

If it doesn't help you can try bypassing the check for large images using filter in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

Also you can try using GD Library instead of ImageMagick for image processing:

```
add_filter('wp_image_editors', function($editors) {
   return ['WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick'];
});
```

Here is an [article](https://vancebell.com/blog/fix-the-wordpress-error-post-processing-of-the-image-failed-likely-because-the-server-is-busy/) that might help.

Edit: Updating above script so it will not cause fatal error.

Comment: I performed a hard refresh and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- Is your image larger that 2500 pixels on the long edge? If so, try reducing its size prior to upload.
- Try the upload in a different web browser.
- Check your filename. Are there any odd characters there, or is it just plain alphanumeric (A-Z/a-z and 0-9) with perhaps underlines or hyphens?
- Try peforming a hard refresh for the edit page in question
- Try emptying your web browser’s cache
- Verify your server upload limit.
- Check your hosting account’s memory usage.

Answer (score -1):

Seemed like wordpress had logged out in the background and i needed to login in again to fix

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue myself. I followed every fix I could find with no help. Finally, I found that I had a plugin called "Big File Uploads" enabled that normally allows you to upload large files, but when turning this off, my error went away and I could upload once again. Hope this helps:)